# keyboard orientation does not work properly in ios6

Tags: keyboard, ios6

I have a problem with auto-rotation and orientation in iOS6. Things they do not work as they used to do in iOS5. Here is what is a sample code.

```
implementation mainProgram
// view controller is defined in landscape mode (.xib file)
// The preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation and supportedInterfaceOrientations have not been defined because they give me problems with getting the orientation right of other calling classes

-(IBAction)somButtonPressed:(id)sender{
      [self presentViewController:inputText animated:NO completion:nil];
 }
 @end

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This has has several  UITextField 
// The view of this controller is defined as landscape in .xib
implementation inputText

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

#if 0  // Disabled
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
#endif

#if 1  // Enabled
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
#endif
@end
```

Questions/Observations: 
1. If supportedInterfaceOrientations is enabled in inputText with a return value of UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight, program will fail saying that preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation is trying to set to an orientation that is not valid even if is exactly the same as in supportedInterfaceOrientations

1. When I try to input text on inputText's one of UITextField the keyboard comes up in portrait mode instead of LandscapeRight. The view of inputText controller is coming up fine in landscapeRight orientation.

It appears to me that they are all bugs in ios6. Has anybody else run to those problems?